# What is the usage of pattern before substitute command in sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

There is an example in this [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-27) about `sed`:

To delete the first number on all lines that start with a "#" use:

```
sed '/^#/ s/[0-9][0-9]*//'
```

What is the benefit of first pattern(`/^#/`)? It could be simply:

```
sed 's/^#[0-9][0-9]*//'
```

Comment: I don't get the `[0-9][0-9]*` why not `[0-9]\+`?

Comment: @Bernhard One good reason is maximum portability.  I don't think `\+` is guaranteed by POSIX.

Comment: @Barnhard I just copied it from the link. But this wikipedia article says that `\+` is in POSIX extended regular expressions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax

Comment: POSIX `sed` uses BRE's though.

Comment: Every modern implementation of sed I've encountered has the ability to use EREs (sometimes with flag `-r`, other times with flag `-E`), and there is talk of adding this capacity to the POSIX standard for `sed`. @jw013 is correct though that the current POSIX standard doesn't require `sed` to handle anything other than BREs. EREs handle plain `+`; some `sed` implementations enhance their BREs to also handle `\+`, but if I remember rightly, this is not part of POSIX. Instead of `p\+` you could use `p\{1,\}`, which is a POSIX BRE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general format of `sed` commands is

> ```
> [address[,address]] function
> ```

When a command has a single address, it operates on all lines that match that address.  When a command has no address, it operates on every single line.

Reference: [POSIX `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

---

Regarding your specific examples:

- `/^#/ s/[0-9][0-9]*//`

  - This command has an address, `/^#/`, which matches all lines beginning with a `#`.
  - The substitution pattern is `/[0-9][0-9]*/`.  This matches the first sequence of digits wherever it occurs in the line.
  - **Plain English summary**: delete the first sequence of digits in every line beginning with a `#`.
  - **Example**: `# non-digits|5555|non-digits|5555` becomes `# non-digits||non-digits|5555`
- `s/^#[0-9][0-9]*//`

  - There is no address, so this command operates on every single line.
  - The substitution pattern, `/^#[0-9][0-9]*/`, matches a sequence of consecutive digits preceded by a `#` *anchored* at the beginning of the line.
  - **Plain English summary**: delete `#` followed by a sequence of digits (and only that pattern) from the beginning of every line.
  - **Example**: `#5555|non-digits|5555` becomes `|non-digits|5555`, but 
    `# non-digits|5555|non-digits|5555` is unchanged because the substitution 
    pattern does not match.

Answer (score 2):

The first will match and substitute:

```
#abc99
```

The second will not.

Plus, the second will also remove the initial `#`.